Official version of Trump shooting
What part of information about shooting of Donald Trump is coming from the official sources and can be considered beyond doubt, and what are just journalistic conjectures and/or political narrative?
Specific examples:

Is it confirmed that Thomas Matthew Crooks was indeed the shooter? That he was a lone shooter? That he was acting on his own initiative?
Was there a failure of Secret Service in letting Trump to be in the shooting range? Have any agents been suspended?
The defiant gesture of Trump raises question as well - by doing so he again exposed himself. Was it another failure by the Secret Service? Could they be sure just a minute after the shooting that it was safe for Trump to show in front of a camera?
How many people were killed/wounded by the gunman, and how many by the Secret service agents/snipers?

Remarks

This is to follow up on question Has there been corroboration from an official government source that Trump was shot? - the wording of this question made it easy to dismiss it as questioning the "obvious" or debating the semantics of term to be shot.
In response to the closure: The question is about political narrative vs. established facts - I am not questioning any mainstream theories here or peddling conspiracy theories here. Thus, this community seems more appropriate than skeptics. Ruling out certain possibilities without questioning seems also rather political (like the shooter might be acting on behalf of a certain political force, or that the defiant moment was to some extent staged (perhaps improvised on the fly, with the collaboration of the Security Services.))


I wonder if sceptics will be more appropriate or not.

Many of these sub questions will certainly be answered in the next days/weeks. On the other hand I wonder where the connection to politics is for the specific questions. Typically ongoing official investigations won't get many comments. Is this maybe more a journalistic topic question?

@NoDataDumpNoContribution The political narrative that possibly disagrees facts or takes for granted facts that are not firmly established is certainly politics. I don't want to engage in conspiracy theories, but was Trump gesture staged PR or a security failure? Was the shooter acting alone or was he a part of a larger (political) conspiracy? I think these are legitimate questions about politics.

@alamar This would likely get closed on skeptics as well due to it being a very current event as they have a close reason just for that. "Questions about unresolved current events and issues currently under investigation by a court of law, government, or other similar investigative body are off-topic because there is insufficient data for a meaningful answer. For more information, see Handling current news questions."

A lot of these questions seem to be things that they are not going know just yet and not going to release even if they did know as it would alert other suspects about where the investigation could be going.

@JoeW A lot of these questions seem to be things that they are not going know just yet and not going to release - the question is specifically about what we do know vs. what we don't know for sure (not about what the answers are). You seem to suggest that all that we read in the news are wild speculations, intended to form political opinions - if you can confirm it, please write an answer.

We have already had some drastic changes to the knowledge that we have about what happened. There was plenty of speculation that Trump was injured by broken glass as a result of the shooting, however know we have solid evidence that there was a bullet that hit his ear.  At this point all we have is speculation and that can do more harm then good if we start spreading it, we just need to give it some time for official information to be released.

@JoeW that can do more harm then good if we start spreading it - the media and politicians have been spreading certain version of events for quite a while now, hence the question, which is specifically about official sources vs. media/politicians.

Just because the media is talking about it non stop doesn't mean that we have to do the same on this site and spread that speculation.

@Morisco "The political narrative that possibly disagrees facts or takes for granted facts that are not firmly established is certainly politics." Then make the question about that and keep it focused. But also keep in mind that we are no better than CNN or the NY times in our investigative abilities, actually much, much worse.

In re #3 bullet. What did you expect the SecServ to do there? Knock him out and carry him unconscious? It's always an issue when the protected person doesn't fully comply with advice, but that's never easy to solve.

Given how close you are to the event, you can pretty much expect that most if not all information given are preliminary.
That being said the FBI has identified a subject involved in the assassination:
The FBI has identified T.M.C., 20, of Bethel Park, Pennsylvania, as the subject involved in the assassination attempt of former President Donald Trump on July 13, in Butler, Pennsylvania.
(Name is given in press release, I'm just not using it in case there's a policy of naming names.)
Now again "involved in the assassination attempt" pretty much means he's the suspected shooter, but at this point all information are more or less preliminary.
According to another release by the FBI the current state of the investigation indicates that the shooter acted alone:

While the investigation to date indicates the shooter acted alone, the FBI continues to conduct logical investigative activity to determine if there were any co-conspirators associated with this attack. At this time, there are no current public safety concerns.

Though as said, they'd be pretty stupid to make any definitive statements while the investigation is likely still ongoing.
The FBI told that about deaths and injuries:

The FBI is investigating the shooting incident at the July 13 rally in Butler, Pennsylvania, which resulted in one victim's death and injuries to former President Trump and other spectators

While apparently the Pennsylvania State Police released their names:
https://www.pa.gov/en/agencies/psp/newsroom/pennsylvania-state-police-identify-victims-shot-during-attempted.html

Was there a failure of Secret Service in letting Trump to be in the shooting range? Have any agents been suspended?

One might suspect that a target having secret service protection being shot at is some kind of failure somewhere. But what went wrong, whether it was preventable in the first place and what precisely happened and how each individual reacted is most likely subject of ongoing investigations which I'd be very surprised if they concluded within days of the event...

The defiant gesture of Trump raises question as well - by doing so he again exposed himself. Was it another failure by the Secret Service? Could they be sure just a minute after the shooting that it was safe for Trump to show in front of a camera?

Yeah that sounds like a very stupid move indeed and the acting of the bodyguard of semi shielding Trump while at least the camera gets an almost unobstructed shot at him looks questionable:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qzRnEzesdNk
That being said there is a lot that we don't know, whether the snipers already confirmed to them that the shooter is dead, whether these are the kinds of bodyguards that would protect of snipers, whether a bodyguard would stand a chance against a potential sniper at all. Whether they were just tasked with getting him out and prepared for melee encounters, whether those temporarily blocking of sight might have already served a purpose. And so on. So yeah that's likely going to be subject of the investigation and I'd be very surprised they will comment on that anytime soon or at all (don't know how willingly they will reveal their tactics and failures of them, to not instruct future events).
So yeah that question is probably too early to be answered with more than the obvious preliminary information that you can get from the official websites of the institutions involved.

FWTW, the FBI says it's not known what object hit Trump. And Trump forbade medical staff from disclosing any details about that. https://youtu.be/2BIdV-DbZ_8?t=117
